# List of Salesforce Formula Values?

Tags: formula, code, default-value

Is there some sort of master list of values like that with a description?

I apologize as I don't know the exact terminology as to what I'm looking for but relevant to Process Builder, I'm looking for a list of code?/values like the ones highlighted below.

Like "TODAY() + 30"; I understand what that's doing but without the Trailhead, I wouldn't have know that existed. So I'm looking for a list sort of like a Bash Command list, that displays the commands and what they do. I hope that helps..

[image]

Comment: Master list of what kind of values? This question is very unclear; could you please edit some context into your question?

Comment: Hi David, I've Edited it*

Answer (score 3):

The expressions you've highlighted are [formulas](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_formuladef.htm&type=5). Formulas are used [in many places in Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_formula_where.htm&type=5), including in the context of Process Builder.

Because formulas are written in an expression language (very broadly analogous to Excel formulas), there's no single list of all available formulas. You can review a list of available [formula functions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions.htm&type=5), explore [formulas](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/point_click_business_logic) on Trailhead, or dig into [advanced formulas](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/advanced_formulas).